# Query Editor - Perform a step based on a Parameter Value

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I want to add a step in my query that does something like, Keep 1 row only if parameter value = 1, if parameter value > 1 then keep all rows.

my parameter name is `param_row_req`

This is my current query,

```
let
    Source = table1,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Year", "Period"}, {{"EffDate", each List.Max([EffDate]), type nullable date}}),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Merged", each Text.Combine({Text.From([Year], "en-GB"), Text.From([Period], "en-GB")}, ""), type text)
in
    #"Inserted Merged Column"
```

How can I do that as a last step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the parameter with an `if` statement and choose the step accordingly

```
let
    Source = table1,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Year", "Period"}, {{"EffDate", each List.Max([EffDate]), type nullable date}}),
    KeepFirstRow = Table.FirstN(#"Grouped Rows",1),
    Result = if param_row_req = 1 then KeepFirstRow else #"Grouped Rows"
in
    Result
```

Adjust the steps to fit your needs